# Zeros of $p$-adic power series and rationality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-analysis, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean field with valuation ring $(V,\mathfrak{m})$, and $K\langle t_1,\ldots, t_n\rangle$ a Tate algebra of convergent power series.

Fix $f \in V\langle t_1,\ldots, t_n\rangle$.

> **Question:** Does there exist an element $g\in K\langle t_1,\ldots, t_n\rangle$ such that
>
> - $g$ is the power series of a rational function
> - the zero loci of $f$ and $g$ in $\text{Sp}\ K\langle t_1,\ldots, t_n\rangle$ agree?

===========

A previous version of the question contained an incorrect attempt at a positive answer.

Comment: I rather doubt the possibility of the inductive process suggested in the second of your three grayed paragraphs. Get yourself a reliable proof with $n=2$ and then see whether you can make a sound proof in the case of $n=3$.

Comment: Consider a series of the form $t_2 + f(t_1)$ where $f$ is a power series but not a polynomial. How do you conclude?

Comment: If $f$, as in @JérômePoineau suggestion, is transcendental and converging in a neighborhood of $0$ with $f(0)=0$, then it's a counterexample because $g(t_1,-f(t_1))$ cannot be identically zero.